# Python - Using Random with No Repeated Words and Selecting a Spare Word from a List

Tags: python, list, random

I'm using the random module in order to display 25 different words. These words are going to be displayed in a 5 by 5 grid. Using a text file which contains 26 words, I want 25 words to be printed in this grid. However, the words printed cannot be repeated and they have to be picked at random. Then how would I be able to get the spare word from that list to use later in the code?

```
with open("file.txt") as x:
        25words= x.read().splitlines()

def 5_by_5(l):
        grid = [listofwords[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(listofwords), 5)]
        for l in grid:
            print("".join("{:10}".format(i) for i in l))

listofwords= [random.choice(25words) for x in range(25)]
```

So at the moment the code can display the 5 by 5 grid but the words are repeated. How do I get it so that every word in the grid is different and then the 26th word that has not been used is identified as something which can be referred to later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could treat your list like a queue.

Sorry, I had to change some of the function names since it wouldn't run otherwise.

```
import random

with open("file.txt") as x:
    words = x.read().splitlines()


def c_grid(l):
    grid = [listofwords[i:i + 5] for i in range(0, len(listofwords), 5)]
    for l in grid:
        print("".join("{:10}".format(i) for i in l))



listofwords = []
for i in range(25):
    myLen = len(words)
    res = random.choice(range(myLen))
    listofwords.append(words.pop(res))

print(listofwords)
c_grid(listofwords)
```

Of if you prefer list comprehension

```
import random

with open("file.txt") as x:
    words = x.read().splitlines()


def c_grid(l):
    grid = [listofwords[i:i + 5] for i in range(0, len(listofwords), 5)]
    for l in grid:
        print("".join("{:10}".format(i) for i in l))


listofwords = [words.pop(random.choice(range(len(words)))) for x in range(25)]
print(listofwords)
c_grid(listofwords)
```

My results:

```
['4', '23', '14', '2', '5', '22', '10', '9', '20', '8', '24', '18', '21', '25', '26', '19', '1', '11', '6', '17', '12', '15', '7', '3', '13']
4         23        14        2         5         
22        10        9         20        8         
24        18        21        25        26        
19        1         11        6         17        
12        15        7         3         13
```

**To get the remaining items:**

```
list_of_unused_words = [x for x in words]

if len(list_of_unused_words) == 1:
    list_of_unused_words = list_of_unused_words[0]

print(list_of_unused_words)
```

The above code makes a list of unused words, incase there is more than just one and saves it to a list. If there is only one, save that one as a single word

Comment: The list comprehension works thank you. So using this how would I then get the number, in your case, that is spare in the list (the 26th word) to be a separate variable?

Comment: So you want the remaining item that hasn't been used as a variable?